# Assignment dimension mismatch MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dimensions

I want to implement an English number recognition in MATLAB using MLP. I have a test set and a train set. I read them at first. Next step is make every files the same size as others.( a fixed size which is maximum the size of longest file) Then I have to make frames of 20ms (sampling rate is 8KHZ) and hamming window with 50% overlapping. And Use LPC(with 12 features).

I get this error `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` I haven't initialized `anninput` to let it get its proper dimension.

```
for i=3:12

    for j=3:192    
   anninput((i-3)*190 +(j-2),:)=reshape(catss,1,2316);
```

Can anyone help me about this error? How should I define `anninput` to solve this problem?

```
catss : 193*12
anninput : 1740x2304 double
```

More detailed code:

```
for i=3:length(directory)   
    folderstring=strcat('C:\Users\...\TrainSet\',directory(i).name);        %//'
    directory1=dir(folderstring);    
    for j=3:length(directory1)     
        lpcTrain=[];        
        for k=1 :wnum-1
            sig=TrainSet{i-2}{j-2};
            if k==1              
                framTrain=sig(1:160);
            else
                framTrain=sig((k-1)*80+1:((k+1)*80)); 
                % // ((k-1).*80)+1 :(k+1).*80
            end
            winTrain=framTrain.* w;  
            cats=lpc(winTrain,12);
            catss(k,:)=cats(2:13); 
        end        
        features=12*(floor(max/80)-1);
        % // features=2316
        n=length(directory1);  
        anninput((i-3)*(190) +(j-2),:)=reshape(catss,1,2316);     
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? anninput has `2304` columns and you are trying to put a `2316` column row into it which obviously won't fit and hence the error... but also the way you've got your code, you'll just be putting the same data into every row. Surely you want to index `catss` with `i` and `j`?

Comment: I want anninput to be a proper input for neural network. 2316 is the total number of lpc features extracted from audio files.How should I define anninput?

Comment: What is `catss`? You need to put way way more detail in your question

Comment: OK sorry.I thought writing dimensions is enough.

Comment: Still not enough. You have to describe your problem, what are you trying to do, what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Why haven't you pre-allocated space for `anninput`? Where does `1740x2304` come from? Also `reshape(catss,1,2316)` flattens your amtrix by going down the columns first, are you sure you don't want to transpose `catss` first?